# sql query to count records by filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query:

```
 SELECT [ScheduleId]
      ,[EventId]
      ,s.[SkillId]
      ,[ADEmployeeId]
      ,sk.[Description]
  FROM [Schedule] s
  INNER JOIN [Skills] sk
  ON s.SkillId = sk.SkillId
  WHERE EventId = 1
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I want to have another column which will say for each description how many positions are available (will count the rows which has the same description) and also one more column which will count how many rows which have same description have ADEmployeeID.

In the example of the image, two additional columns should have data like this:

1 | 1

3 | 1

1 | 0

3 | 1

3 | 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want window functions:

```
SELECT [ScheduleId],[EventId], s.[SkillId], [ADEmployeeId], sk.[Description],
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sk.Description) as col1,
       COUNT(ADEmployeeId) OVER (PARTITION BY sk.Description) as col2
FROM [Schedule] s INNER JOIN
     [Skills] sk
     ON s.SkillId = sk.SkillId
WHERE EventId = 1;
```